# Convert non-strict JSON Amazon SNAP metadata to Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, apache-spark, ibm-cloud

I am trying to convert [this Amazon sample Snap grocery JSON data](http://snap.stanford.edu/data/amazon/productGraph/categoryFiles/meta_Grocery_and_Gourmet_Food.json.gz) to a Pandas dataframe in IBM Bluemix (using Python 2.x) and then analyze it with Apache Spark.

I have unzipped the JSON file and uploaded it to an Apache Spark Container.

Here is my container connection:

```
# In[ ]:

credentials_1 = {
  'auth_uri':'',
  'global_account_auth_uri':'',
  'username':'myUname',
  'password':"myPw",
  'auth_url':'https://identity.open.softlayer.com',
  'project':'object_storage_988dfce6_5b93_48fc_9575_198bbed3abfc',
  'project_id':'2c05de8a36d74d32bdbe0eeec7e5a372',
  'region':'dallas',
  'user_id':'4976489bab7d489f8d2eba681adacb78',
  'domain_id':'8b6bc3e989d644858d7b74f24119447a',
  'domain_name':'1079761',
  'filename':'meta_Grocery_and_Gourmet_Food.json',
  'container':'grocery',
  'tenantId':'s31d-8e24c13d9c36f4-43b43b7b993d'
}
```

I then used Apache Spark's sample of importing data from container to StringIO

```
# In[ ]:

import requests, StringIO, pandas as pd, json, re


    # In[ ]:

    def get_file_content(credentials):
        """For given credentials, this functions returns a StringIO object containing the file content."""

        url1 = ''.join([credentials['auth_url'], '/v3/auth/tokens'])
        data = {'auth': {'identity': {'methods': ['password'],
                'password': {'user': {'name': credentials['username'],'domain': {'id': credentials['domain_id']},
                'password': credentials['password']}}}}}
        headers1 = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
        resp1 = requests.post(url=url1, data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers1)
        resp1_body = resp1.json()
        for e1 in resp1_body['token']['catalog']:
            if(e1['type']=='object-store'):
                for e2 in e1['endpoints']:
                    if(e2['interface']=='public'and e2['region']==credentials['region']):
                        url2 = ''.join([e2['url'],'/', credentials['container'], '/', credentials['filename']])
        s_subject_token = resp1.headers['x-subject-token']
        headers2 = {'X-Auth-Token': s_subject_token, 'accept': 'application/json'}
        resp2 = requests.get(url=url2, headers=headers2)
        return StringIO.StringIO(resp2.content)
```

I then converted the String content to a strict JSON pattern by appending [ and  ] at the beginning and at the end and by separating the data with a comma.

```
print('----------------------\n')

import json

myDf=[];

def parse(data):
    for l in data:
        yield json.dumps(eval(l))

def getDF(data):
    st='['
    i = 0
    df =[]
    for d in parse(data):
        if i<100:
            i += 1
            #print(str(d))
            st=st+str(d)+','
            #print('----------------\n')
    st=st[:-1]
    st=st+']'
    #js=json.loads(st)
    #print(json.dumps(js))
    return pd.read_json(st)

content_string = get_file_content(credentials_1)

df = getDF(content_string)
df.head()
```

I am getting a perfectly desirable result.
[Output of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wivZh.png)

The problem is that when I remove i < 100 condition, it just never completes and the kernel remains busy for over one hour.

Is there any other elegant ways to convert the the data into dataframe?

Also, ijson is not available with Bluemix Notebook.

Answer (score 0):

Let me answer this in two parts:-

1. You can install ijson in your bluemix spark service using below command and then user `import ijson` to further use it as per your use.

   `!pip install --user ijson`
2. You can use `sqlContext.jsonFile` to read the json from object storage rather than going around to define your schema.
   This will even infer the schema for you and then you can run some spark-sql queries to do whatever you want with the dataframe.

   `df = sqlContext.jsonFile("swift://" + objectStorageCreds['container'] + "." + objectStorageCreds['name'] + "/" + objectStorageCreds['filename'])`

Here is the link to complete [notebook](https://github.com/charles2588/bluemixsparknotebooks/blob/master/Python/json_parser.ipynb).

If you have to work with pandas dataframe , you can simply convert it to

```
df.toPandas().head()
```

But this will cause to get everything at the driver node(use carefully).

Thanks,
Charles.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks you so much. Just a simple change in my case, I had to change the URL pattern. df = sqlContext.read.json("swift://" + objectStorageCreds['container'] + ".spark"  + "/" + objectStorageCreds['filename']) . ".spark" seems to be needed for working with Apache spark. So, the objectStorageCreds['name'] can be set to 'spark'. Thanks again. Works like a charm.